# Как получить максимальную ширину элемента которого нет в доме

Tags: javascript, html

Есть таблица. Некоторые ячейки не в доме, ведь мешает скролл. Нужно получить стили и максимальную ширину элемента, которого еще нет в доме.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Максимальная ширина должна быть что-то около бесконечности (если не учитывать возможности ПК)

Comment: @ArchDemon в данной таблице есть ячейки и  фиксированая ширина  ( есть таблица со скролом и есть фукция double click  когда на колонке вызывается  эта функция то она берет макисмальную ширину всех видимих колонок  , но есть колонки которіе вне дома и нужно также учитівать их макс ширину  как за ранее просчитать максимальную ширину колонки до рендора в доме

Comment: ну если у вас ширина колонок фиксированная, то что вам мешает просуммировать все нужные колонки?

Comment: @ArchDemon хорошо а как тогда просумировать те колонки которіе еще в не дома и узнать их максимальную нужную им ширину для отображения всего елемента

Comment: Приведите код, который бы воспроизводил проблему. Тогда Вам предложат варианты. (да, надо потрудиться, если нужно решение)